# how do I convert a base ten representation to its equivalent two's complement in 7 bit?

Tags: radix, complement

how do I convert a base ten representation to its equivalent two's complement in 7 bit?
I am learning applications of discrete mathematics and this is one of the questions, being new to this, I just don't understand

Answer (score 0):

your question lacks some details, especially concerning the environment in which you are working. Do you want to do it by hand or in a specific programming language? What steps did you take to solve the problem by yourself? If you did so, why didn't they answer your question?

Please read more about asking question at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Furthermore you are asking two separable questions.

All of this contributes to your negative score.

To convert from 10-base to 2-base 2-complement, convert 10-base to 2-base 1-complement and from there to 2-base 2-complement.

From your second question I deduct you have been working on your problem. So I think you already know http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#From_the_ones.27_complement. There is also a nice example.

Flipping a bit means using the NOT-operation on the bit, simply said: turn a 0 into 1 and vice versa. Adding one means increasing the value of the numer by one.